# How to query multi value in mogoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

- I am a beginner to use mogoDB (json/noSQL). Please help me using the query in mogoDB. In SQL i use like :

```
select * from account where 'status'='active' and 
('create_by'= 'USE001' or 'create_by' = 'USE004' or 'create_by' = 'USE035')".
```

- In mogoDB (json/noSQL), How can i do it ??
- This is my data structure:

```
{
   "id":"ACC0001",
   "create_day":"2020-04-20 16:56:11",
   "create_by":"USE001",
   "brief_name":"AAAAA",
   "status":"active"
},
{
   "id":"ACC0002",
   "create_day":"2020-04-20 16:56:12",
   "create_by":"USE002",
   "brief_name":"BBBBB",
   "status":"inactive"
},
{
   "id":"ACC0003",
   "create_day":"2020-04-20 16:56:13",
   "create_by":"USE003",
   "brief_name":"CCCCC",
   "status":"active"
},
{
   "id":"ACC0004",
   "create_day":"2020-04-20 16:56:14",
   "create_by":"USE004",
   "brief_name":"DDDDD",
   "status":"inactive"
},
{
   "id":"ACC9999",
   "create_day":"2020-04-20 16:56:15",
   "create_by":"USE100",
   "brief_name":"FFFFF",
   "status":"active"
}
```

Comment: are you sure `root.account` is an object?

Comment: Is this your real data? This is **one** document, i.e. in terms of SQL this is one single row. Do you like to get only partial data of that document?

Comment: Thanks @varman; @Wernfried Domscheit. I update my data structure. Because I am a newbie, I don't have a lot of experience with noSQL in terms of structure or query. Thanks for the comments

Comment: Actually dont upload image files, what you have posted previously is correct, this is wrong. U need to post whole structure of an object. Please edit and upload whole structre of sample data

Comment: And you have `root` object. It has a property called `account`. I need to know that `account` is an objext or an array?

Comment: thanks you so much !!! i has fix it, is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can translate your query into the following, note my use of the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator.

```js
db.account.find({
  status: "active",
  create_by: { $in: [ "USE001", "USE004", "USE035" ] }
})
```

You could technically also run this as the query below, however, mongo recommends using `$in` over `$or` if you're doing equality checks on the same field. I'm mentioning this since you weren't using `IN` in your original MySQL query. See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-versus-in

```js
db.account.find({
  status: "active",
  $or: [
    { create_by: "USE001" },
    { create_by: "USE004" },
    { create_by: "USE035" }
  ]
})
```

Comment: tks you so much. Thanks for the knowledge you shared so helpful to me !!!!